# How to analyze and connect rows in multiple csv files (python)

Tags: python, data-analysis

I have multiple csv files that are all of format:
date, time, name1, name2, number1,number2,number3,number4,number5,number6,number7

What i want to do is get the max numbers1-7 by connecting rows from different files with a criteria that the date, time, name1, name2 are equal. I couldn't find a solution of what kind of structures are best to use and the all in all how should i structure my algorithm to be as optimal as possible.

Only idea is to just bruteforce it and try to match every row from one file with all of the other files but its not time efficient.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

# Read CSV files
def read_csv(filename):
    data = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in reader:
            data.append(row)
    return data

# Combine data
def combine_data(files):
    combined_data = defaultdict(list)
    for file in files:
        data = read_csv(file)
        for row in data:
            key = (row['date'], row['time'], row['name1'], row['name2'])
            combined_data[key].append((row, file))  # Store file name along with row
    return combined_data

# Find maximums
def find_maximums(combined_data):
    max_values = {}
    for key, rows in combined_data.items():
        max_values[key] = {}
        for column in ['number1', 'number2', 'number3', 'number4', 'number5', 'number6', 'number7']:
            max_value = max(rows, key=lambda x: float(x[0][column]))  # Get max row using lambda function
            max_values[key][column] = {'value': max_value[0][column], 'file': max_value[1]}  # Store max value and file name
    return max_values

# Function to calculate similarity between two strings using SequenceMatcher
def similarity(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']  # List of CSV files
    combined_data = combine_data(files)
    max_values = find_maximums(combined_data)
    for key, values in max_values.items():
        print(f"Combination: {key}")
        for column, info in values.items():
            max_value = info['value']
            file_name = info['file']
            print(f"Max {column} ({file_name}): {max_value}")
```

Comment: Sorry for not adding it in my initial question but is there a way to flag from which file the max is?

Comment: And is it possible to use a criteria of similarity for the name1 and name2 columns like difflib sequence matcher since the names don't always match exactly

Comment: To flag from which file the maximum value is obtained, you can modify the find_maximums function to keep track of the file names along with the maximum values. Additionally, you can use the SequenceMatcher from the difflib module to compare the similarity between names in the name1 and name2 columns. .. please try updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply read each line and update a `dict`:

- if the key (i.e. date, time, name1, name2) is not present then set it with the current row values;
- if the key is already in the dict compare between what's in the dict and in the current row for each number position, and update the numbers list as needed

```
filenames = ['f1.csv', 'f2.csv']
key_cols = 4
val_cols = 7
max_values = {}
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.Reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            k = row[:key_cols]
            v = row[key_cols+1:]
            if k not in max_values:
                max_values[k] = v
            else:
                for i in range(val_cols):
                    if v[i] > max_values[k][i]:
                        max_values[k][i] = v[i]
```

This is simple, and both time- and space-efficient